# What is the FME Equivalent to the ArcGIS Union tool?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, fme-form, analysis, arctoolbox, union

I'm attempting to union 2 large featureclasses in ArcCatalog, QGIS, and FME.  What is the transformer that would be equivalent to the [ArcGIS Union tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000000s000000)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe the [AreaOnAreaOverlayer](https://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/areaonareaoverlayer.htm) is the transformer that performs the equivalent of an ArcGIS Union.

> Performs an area-on-area overlay so that all input areas are intersected against each other and resultant area features are created and output. The resultant areas have all the attributes of all the original features in which they are contained.
> [image: AreaOnAreaOverLayer example]
> <sub>(source: [safe.com](http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Resources/Images/AreaOnAreaOverlayerExample01.png))</sub>